# Flutter for loop not being called

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a rough clone of Reddit using flutter to help me learn but I'm getting stuck where my for loop isn't being called, in initialisation. The part of my code where it fails is here:

```
class RedditTable extends StatelessWidget {
  List posts;
  List containers;
  RedditTable(List posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
    this.containers = new List<Container>();

    for (var i = 0; i == posts.length; i++) {
      var post = posts[i]["data"];
      var title = post["title"];
      var container = new Container(
          margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
          child: new Text(title)
      );
      containers.add(container);
    }
  }
```

The for loop isn't being called and hence the containers list is not being populated. When I print `posts.length` just before the loop I get an output of 25 but doing the same thing in the loop returns nothing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++)` instead of `for (var i = 0; i == posts.length; i++)`.

As you don't really use `i` you can use for-in or list transformation:

```dart
    for (var post in posts) {
      var title = post["data"]["title"];
      var container = new Container(
        margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
        child: new Text(title),
      );
      containers.add(container);
    }

    // or 

    containers = posts.map((post) => new Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
      child: new Text(post["data"]["title"]),
    )).toList();
```

Comment: I have encountered the same issue and this solution worked perfectly. Why is the equivalent operator not working?